# How to turn off the white frame in vscode theme one dark pro?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I'm using the [One Dark Pro](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zhuangtongfa.Material-theme) theme in Visual Studio Code. I found that there are white frames around variables, function names, macros, etc. when I use this theme. How can I turn off this feature (the white frames)?

[image]

Comment: find the TextMate scope and customize the decoration

Comment: But I don't know which scope can control it. Please tell me.

Comment: what does a search on SO for `TextMate scope` and tag `visual-studio-code` give for result

Comment: @rioV8 - I understand you don't want to do all the work for them, but you could've just given them a link...

Comment: @Cyb3rst0rm then I do all the work/search for them

Comment: @rioV8 - Okay, understandable.

Comment: @rioV8 - It comes out that a vscode setting control that border. The setting is "workbench.colorCustomizations"-"editor.selectionHighlightBorder". If you don't want the border, you can just set it transparent. Thank you for your help!

Comment: you did not mention that you only see this if you **select** part of the file, I have used One Dark Pro and do not remember that it used boxes, had you defined this `editor.selectionHighlightBorder` yourself, before asking, for a different theme, you can customize these color per theme in `settings.json`

Comment: I haven't made any change after using One Dark Pro, so the border was there originally. And next time I will make my question clearer. Thank you for your help again.